# Access linked to SQL with SSMA slow performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, ms-access, ssma, query-performance

I'm working on migrating a legacy application's DB (in Access 2003 format) to a SQL Server 2008 back-end (This will be upgraded later on).  We are close to hitting the 2GB size limit in Access and performance is starting to degrade, even with up to date indexes and constant compacts.

I have successfully migrated the data into a SQL DB via SQLServer Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Access 2017, after fixing a few issues with tables not having primary keys.  I am able to access the data through the legacy application as normal, but the data access during load is now taking up to 45 seconds for the initial query compared to 1 or 2 before the migration.  Performance seems to improve after the initial load, however.

I have loaded the application and watched on the SQL activity monitor the requests coming in, and the worst offender at 22 seconds is just a simple select:

```
SELECT "Id"
FROM "dbo"."Table" "t"
```

The table itself has a little under 11,000 rows, and the query runs almost instantly through management studio, while taking around the same time running through Access and using the linked tables.

The Access DB is on the same machine and same drive as the SQL DB, and is not going out over the network.  Both are currently being run inside of a VM for testing purposes.

Is there any way to speed up my queries using this method?  Activity monitor is not showing any heavy CPU or I/O use during these queries so I do not think those are having a large effect on performance.

Comment: Is there an index on that column?

Comment: The tables are all indexed on their primary keys.  I tried adding extra on the SQL server side and rebuilding them all with no luck.

Comment: Is *that* column indexed? Is that the primary key? Is it specifically *defined* as the primary key? (Not just an index) And does the linked table definition in msaccess know that this is a primary key?